# Sockets using SSL in Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: sockets, ssl, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm using Titanium Alloy to build a mobile app, and need to access our *IRC* for one of the features. I've set up a socket using `Ti.Network.Socket.createTCP()`, which connects successfully, but after I send anything over the socket I get a 54 error:

`The operation couldn’t be completed. Connection reset by peer`.

I believe the problem here is that Titanium sockets do not support SSL connections, which our IRC requires.

I've been looking into socket SSL for Titanium quite a bit. The Appcelerator docs do not mention `SSL/TLS` at all, and all posts I've found related to these features missing seem to be from 2011, with no workarounds.

No luck on finding any modules that solve this either.

Is there a way to set up Titanium sockets to connect using SSL?

If not, is there a workaround/module that can allow me to do this?

Comment: SSL support for `Ti.Network.Socket.createTCP()` might make a great feature request. Stack Overflow is [not the right place](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company) for that. Please check if it has already been requested at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). If it has not, create a ticket, link to this question but also provide a complete description in the ticket. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.

Comment: Here are some tickets that were created a long time ago - [iOS](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-6211) and [Android](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-6212).

There doesn't seem to have been any progress with it, so I'm looking for other options.

Answer (score 0):

You could use SocketIO (on the server side) and for the Titanium App for iOS & Android, you could use this module, which works well (from personal experience): https://github.com/omorandi/tiws

Comment: Unfortunately we cannot connect to the IRC with a WebSocket, and we cannot change our server-side implementation since we use it on other platforms as well.